# QPixmap don't show my picture

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I'm trying to display a picture on a QLabel with a QPixmap, but the image doesn't show. Can somebody help me?

```
onglets = new QTabWidget(this);    //création des onglets
page1 = new QWidget;  //création de la page 1
page2 = new QLabel; //création de la page 2

page1->setLayout(layoutPrincipal); //insere le layoutprincipale dans la page 1
page2->setPixmap(QPixmap("1.png"));
page2->setText("Alpha version 1.0");
onglets->addTab(page1, "Creation de compte"); //ajoute la page 1 dans les onglets
onglets->addTab(page2, "A propos");
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that happens because a QLabel can't have a text and a pixmap simultaneously.

Comment: i try without the text but it still doesn't want to show the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in lines:

```
page2->setPixmap(QPixmap("1.png"));
page2->setText("Alpha version 1.0");
```

QLabel can't have both text and Pixmap options, so, when you setText, QPixmap is removed. To avoid this, you can create new QWidget for second tab of your QTabWidget, add there 2 QLabels, with 1, that have text and second - pixmap.

UPDATE:
if after removing `page2->setText("Alpha version 1.0");` QPixmap still is not present, try to find out, if there even exist file "1.png". Try this out, to determine, if file exists and it where you expect it to be

```
qDebug()<<"File exists -"<<QFileInfo("1.png").exists()<<" "<<QFileInfo("1.png").absoluteFilePath();
```

UPDATE2:

When you launch it from QtCreator (compile it), your file should be in your project directory (near *.pro file), when you launch it from executable, it should be near it, if you invoke it like "1.png". By the way, if you change your `currentWorkingDirectory` - then next problems will arise. The solution is to add qt recource file to project and add this image to recource and call it like `QPixmap(:/1.png");`. But for now, you can find the required directory with `QDir::currentPath()`, put your file there.

Comment: thank you for the answer but it seems it's not that the problem, i've just delete this lign but the picture still doesn't want to show.

Comment: @DanSnow have commented out only `page2->setText("Alpha version 1.0");
` ? Updated answer by the way.

Comment: yes i was talking about this lign    page2->setText("Alpha version 1.0");

Comment: @DanSnow updated answer, probably pixmap is in the wrong directory

Comment: in which directory the directory should I put the image? I tried in almost every folder but it doesn't work. (I use Qt 5.1.0 and Qt creator 2.7.2)

Comment: qDebug said me "File exists - false   "C:/Users/allan/Desktop/QT test/sans_titre/build-yo-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/1.png" " but when i check in the folder i can see my picture (sorry for my bad english i'm french)

Comment: @DanSnow well, it expects file "1.png" in directory "C:/Users/allan/Desktop/QT test/sans_titre/build-yo-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/" but cannot find it, so if you put it there, all should work

Comment: @DanSnow try to add recource file or add image to `qDebug()<<QDir::currentPath();`

Comment: thank you very much, you help me solve my problem, in fact Qt creat an other folder where it was asking for my picture, this folder is different than I was expecting. Thank you again :) . Doyou know where I can found a good tutorial to make file ressource ?

Comment: @DanSnow well, glad, that i helped you, you can check this for example - http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in-1.1.7/vs-addin-managing-resources.html